# Qual è il senso di "conto" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> I due maschi, uno è un po’ piú vecchio di me e l’altro un po’ piú giovane. Con loro ci facevo quattro parole a testa al giorno, ma nessuno dei due m’ha mai trattato con prepotenza, forse perché sapevano bene che bastava una tempesta un po’ arrabbiata e un piccolo **conto** nella testa di loro padre per spedirli tutt’e due a far la mia medesima fine lontano da casa.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "conto" in parecchi dizionari ma, ce ne sono tante accezioni, che non sono sicura di aver capito qual è l'adatta al contesto del testo. Quindi la domanda sarebbe: nel brano sopra citato, "conto" sta per "racconto"?

Comment: Sicuramente non significa racconto, però mi pare che potrebbe significare pensiero, preoccupazione.

Comment: It seems to me that this is in the sense of a 'mental calculation' that the father would do in his head.

Comment: Sono d'accordo col commento di @AnyAD anche secondo me il padre "calcola" mentalmente quanto convenga tenersi in casa i due "maschi" di cui si parla e poi li sbatte fuori di casa senza troppe smancerie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nel brano sopra citato, "conto" NON sta per "racconto" ma significa letteralmente "conto" nella piú comune accezione di sequenza di operazioni aritmetiche.

> *"[...] bastava una tempesta un po’ arrabbiata e un piccolo **conto** nella testa di loro padre per spedirli tutt’e due a far la mia medesima fine lontano da casa."*

Una *tempesta un po’ arrabbiata* produce un buco nel bilancio dell'azienda agricola familiare e un piccolo *conto* (letteralmente) potrebbe poi indicare al padre la opportunità di avere due bocche in meno da sfamare o, in altri termini, di mandare i due uomini a lavorare sotto padrone lontano dalla loro casa, così come successo alla voce narrante.

Comment: Cosa vuol dire "conto" significa letteralmente "conto"? Perché, come ho spiegato nella domanda, ho cercato questo vocabolo in parecchi dizionari e ho trovato molte accezioni, tra le quali quella di "racconto".

Comment: Un conto, divisioni, sottrazioni, moltiplicazioni... _"La cascina rende 200 lire, siamo in 8,  25 lire a testa, la tempesta mi ha fatto danni per 200 lire e finché non le reinvesto la cascina mi rende 180 lire, se siamo in 6 a 25 lire  ho 30 lire da investire ogni anno... Oh voi due ragazzi, ho qualcosa da dirvi..."_

Answer (score 2):

In questo contesto significa "calcolo mentale", ragionamento.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: Potresti aggiungere qualche particolare alla tua risposta?

Answer (score -1):

“*Conto nella testa del padre*”

**Significa qualche “*problema*”, qualcosa che fa preoccupare il padre.**

Nelle frasi seguenti si fa riferimento al padre che sembra arrabbiato e ***spedirebbe i figli lontano da casa*** pertanto è più un “*pensiero*” del padre preoccupato che un “*calcolo mentale*”.

Se il racconto si svolge in una **piccola città o in campagna** quasi sicuramente è riferito a un modo di dire dialettale.

Ci sono tante varianti dell’uso di alcune parole in Italiano ma, come in inglese, si può trovare il senso semplicemente dal **contesto**.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Il romanzo è ambientato nelle Langhe durante la prima metà del Novecento. L'io narrante è un ragazzo contadino.

Comment: Non capisco perché la frase non debba essere corretta dal punto di vista grammaticale.

Comment: Allora è sicuramente un modo di dire, conto=problema, preoccupazione, pensiero

Comment: Non si deve cogliere il senso *letterale* delle frasi. “Conto nella testa del padre” è un modo di dire contadino, semplice. Grammaticalmente è corretta ma la frase non significa che il padre ha *letteralmente* un conto nella testa, significa che è preoccupato/stressato.

Comment: E allora, se “grammaticalmente è corretta” come mai scrivi che è “non troppo corretto dal punto di vista grammaticale”?

Comment: @DaG non ho detto che è sbagliato infatti, ho detto che non è troppo corretto. Una cosa corretta è una cosa che non lascia spazio a interpretazioni sbagliate, è corretta e chiara. Una cosa del genere scritta così lascia spazio a molti dubbi e per rispondere e fare chiarezza ho usato quella frase. Quasi senza pensarci troppo.

Comment: @DaG comunque visto che vi da così tanto fastidio questa imperfezione nella mia risposta, comunque giusta (spero) l’ho tolta

Comment: Più che fastidio, non era molto chiaro, visto che nella risposta dicevi una cosa e nei commenti un'altra. Grazie per la modifica.

Comment: @DaG l’importante è chiarirsi. Prego.